# LINQ to SQL Code-First: ColumnAttribute.Expression (Relationships)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

In a parent Entity, is there anyway to set a column's `ColumnAttribute.Expression` string pointing at the referenced `EntitySet<ChildEntity>` Count or is the `Expression` only computed from columns in the same Entity?

**EDIT:**

`[Column(Expression = "ChildEntitySet.Count")]` throws an exception.

`[Column(Expression = "COUNT(ChildEntitySet)")]` throws an exception too.